# Encapsulation Pattern to Use with AngularJS

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, architecture, data-modeling

I need to create smart objects/functions in Javascript to use with my AngularJS app. What pattern should I use for this? I currently am using the generic JavaScript 'module' pattern which I researched, but I am wondering if I should be modeling these object/functions (below) in an AngularJS-way. Perhaps as 'services'?

I come from a Java background which makes me a little uncomfortable calling a object with helper methods a 'service.' But I may need to adjust my definitions for JavaScript/AngularJS.

The app is a basic grading system. The two main objects/functions are below:

**LessonScoreCard**

```
/* 
 * LessonScoreCard
 * 
 * Is a "module" that keeps track of the score a user has for a given lesson
 * and whether or not for a given question there are more correct answers 
 * that can be made.
 */

var lessonScoreCard = (function() {

    //Map of questions to scores
    var privateQuestionNumberToScoreMap = {};

    //API to be used by external clients
    var publicAPI = {

        //A public function utilizing privates
        setScore: function(questionNumber, score) {
            privateQuestionNumberToScoreMap[ questionNumber ] = score;
        },

        //Sum the total score
        getTotalScore: function( ){
            var totalScore = 0;
            for( var questionNumber in privateQuestionNumberToScoreMap ){
                totalScore += privateQuestionNumberToScoreMap[questionNumber];
            }
        }
    };

    return publicAPI;
})();
```

**Answer Key**

```
/* 
 * AnswerKey
 * 
 * Is a "module" that takes an answer key and performs functions
 * related to it.
 */

var answerKey = (function() {

    //Set of right answers
    var privateQuestionNumberToAnswerArrayMap;

    //API to be used by external clients
    var publicAPI = {
        setAnswerKey: function(answerKeyModel) {
            privateQuestionNumberToAnswerArrayMap = answerKeyModel;
        },
        // A public function utilizing privates
        isCorrect: function(question, answer) {
            var isCorrect = false;

            var answerArray = privateQuestionNumberToAnswerArrayMap[ question ];
            if (answerArray.indexOf(answer) !== -1) {
                isCorrect = true;
            }
            return isCorrect;
        },

        getAnswerCount: function( question ){
            var answerArray = privateQuestionNumberToAnswerArrayMap[ question ];
            return answerArray.length;
        }

    };

    return publicAPI;

})();
```

**Sample JSON Answer Key Model**

```
    {
        1: [1, 3],
        2: [4]
    }
```

Comment: Making it an Angular service means the module is "more usable" in an Angular project, so I usually base my decision on: will I use it outside Angular? Also, will I be using DI in some way, especially for testing the module, and if so, then yes, I would convert to an Angular service.

Comment: @aet: It is more of data model with helper methods than a 'service.' I may be caught up on the naming here. Services to me seems more like it does something, which these objects/functions don't do.

Comment: A "service" in angular is basically that, or at least is often used in that manner - a model object which exposes some data. Especially if the data will be used by multiple controllers. I still think in a sort of MVCish way, and to me the services in angular are like models, html as view, and controllers are the "glue" between the views and models.

Comment: @aet: Thanks. Certainly that would make more sense from a functional (not functional-programming) perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aet is right, but I would expand the role of services even further. Services and directives are your two primary building blocks when constructing an app on top of Angular.

Directives are *tightly coupled* to the view. They are for:

1. Changing some data in response to user input or action
2. Updating the UI in response to a change in data

Services are very *uncoupled* from the view. They're for:

1. Encapsulating business logic
2. Storing more robust model data that you want to share throughout your app, especially if your app is so large that it has more than 1 controller, or if your model data is tightly coupled to a persistence mechanism (e.g. [a Backbone model](http://backbonejs.org/#Model))

So services can really do or be anything, as long as that thing isn't view-related. I think you should write your lessonScoreCard and answerKey modules as service factories, and inject them into any directives which need access to their functionality.